# EF Core IQueryable, Count() efficiency and best practices

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I'm writing queries (CQRS pattern) using EF Core 6 that will be consumed by my controller. Besides of the view models I would also like to return some additional data to the client to enable proper pagination (eg. total count, returned count and remaining count).

My original query looked like this:

```
_posts //DbSet
    .Where(x => x.Status.Equals(PostStatus.Published))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
    .Where(x => x.CreatedAt < createdAtCursor) //cursor pagination based on created at date
    .Include(x => x.Translations
        .Where(x => x.Language.Equals(language)))
    .Where(x => x.Translations != null) //excluding all posts without translation in a given language
    .Take(pageSize)
    .Select(x => x.ToPreviewModel())
    .AsNoTracking();
```

So I came up with the following solutions:

**Option 1:** Split query, run `CountAsync()` in-between

```
var allPublishedPosts = _posts
        .Where(x => x.Status.Equals(PostStatus.Published))
        .Include(x => x.Translations
            .Where(x => x.Language.Equals(language)))
        .Where(x => x.Translations != null);

int totalCount = await allPublishedPosts
    .CountAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

var olderThanPublishedPosts = allPublishedPosts
    .Where(x => x.CreatedAt < createdAtCursor);

int olderThanCount = await olderThanPublishedPosts
    .CountAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

var returnedPublishedPosts = olderThanPublishedPosts
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
     .Take(pageSize)
     .Select(x => x.ToPreviewModel())
     .AsNoTracking();

int returnedCount = await returnedPublishedPosts
    .CountAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here I'm worried about `Include()` being on top of the query - I guess that could be quite expensive to run this command on a larger set than in original query and I also need to call db 3 times and wait for every `CountAsync()` one by one to finish.

**Option 2:** Split query, re-write it to take `DbContext`//`DbSet` as a parameter and run `CountAsync()` in parallel on multiple contexts

```
IQueryable<PostBase> allPublishedPostsQuery(DbSet<PostBase> posts) =>
    posts
        .Where(x => x.Status.Equals(PostStatus.Published))
        .Include(x => x.Translations
            .Where(x => x.Language.Equals(language)))
        .Where(x => x.Translations != null);

//...so on for the other parts of the query

int[]? countResults;
using (var context1 = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
using (var context2 = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
using (var context3 = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    countResults = await Task.WhenAll(
        allPublishedPostsQuery(context1.Posts)
            .CountAsync(),
        olderThanPublishedPostsQuery(context2.Posts)
            .CountAsync(),
        returnedPublishedPostsQuery(context3.Posts)
            .CountAsync())
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
};

int totalPostsCount = countResults[0];
int olderThanPostsCount = countResults[1];
int returnedPostsCount = countResults[2];
```

Looks like an overkill to me, but I don't know performance-wise. It's a pity we cannot do it on a single context.

**Option 3:** ???
Ideally I would like to do it in a one complete query, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Eventually I could leave all the calculations to the front-end and provide only total count, but still I'm curious for the future how to solve it in a best way and possibly improve efficiency of the query itself.

Comment: 'So I came up with the following solutions:' --- but what's exactly the problem?

Comment: Why not run all of the options and benchmark the results? Considering we have no window into what the tables look like behind these entities, or the indexes on them, we can only make guesses as to the plans the queries resulting from these options would produce. When it comes to performance, the best thing you can do is try it into the scenario you find yourself in and see. Sure, SO and other sites can give some general tips, but really, it's a matter of learning what EF does to make queries and how SQL Server (or whatever backing store you're using) interprets that.

Comment: If you really want to get the best possible performance for this, then you'd have to use a [raw SQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql), which you can use to get [all the counts at once](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+return+multiple+counts). Whether it's worth the effort is up to you to decide.

Comment: Thanks guys for your feedback. @Lei Yang, the problem is how to efficiently use queries (preferrably via EF Core) along with multiple counts.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, you are completely right, but unfortunately as a beginner I might have a wrong understanding of certain mechanisms and after dozens of benchmarking and searching still not even be close to finding the best way. But if you say there is nothing entirely stupid in this piece of code and there are no issues you are aware of in advance, I will for sure dig deeper :)

Comment: if you are only counting, i think performance is good enough. and since counting is readonly, you can cache.

Comment: @Gabriel Luci, I was not aware that this is possible even im SQL. I will check what will be the efforts/performance ratio since I somehow dont get along with SQL.

Comment: 1) 3 separate context? Instead you can turn on multiple result sets in your connection string. 2) I assume you mean `.Skip(...).Take(...)` for pagination. 3) If you are returning the current page of records, you can count them in memory instead of via sql.

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to pagination, most controls just want a row count along with a page size and page #. For the most part EF is pretty efficient when you tell it to fetch a count. There shouldn't be a need to execute multiple counts. I'll typically just leave off `OrderBy*` clauses off the query, take the count, then append the `OrderBy*` clauses and fetch the page of data.

That said, with very large datasets and potentially dynamic criteria used to filter that data, count queries can get fairly expensive. If you are facing a situation where you're potentially looking at very large count values and slow count queries, What I can suggest is a bit of a "cheat":

Take a situation where you have a pagination control set to a page size of 50 and you display 10 page selectors at a time. 1-10 then a >> if more pages.

Build the query without OrderBy/Pagination.
Based on the selected page number, determine how many sets of 10 pages need to be loaded:

```
var pages = ((pageNumber / 10) +1) * 10;
```

So for instance if loading page 1, pages = 10. If loading page 11 or 12, pages = 20.

Next, limit your total rows based on the pages needed + 1 row, and base your count on this figure.

```
var count = query.Take(pages * pageSize + 1).Count();
```

Lastly, check the count against pages * pageSize + 1, if it is equal you have more pages worth to load, otherwise the count reflects the actual number of records.

What this gives you is an adaptive page count. When loading the first page of results it will Count over a maximum of 500 rows (page size of 50, 10 pages). If there are <= 500 rows the pagination control will display the correct # of pages and we can display the actual count. If there are > 500 rows then the pagination will display 10 pages plus expects an 11th page (rendering in the next page >> control), and we display the row count as something like "500+" or "at least 500" rather than the specific count. Where the client may want to get an accurate row count for whatever reason, I will render this as a hyperlink that will actually do a full count and update the total.  *If* the user selects the >> next page, requesting page #11, the count check bumps to limit at 20 pages rather than 10. If there are more than 1000 results the rendering would show pages 11-20 /w the >> next page, and a row count of "1000+".

The limitation of this approach is that you cannot give the user the ability to go to a specific page or show the accurate row count for every query unless they explicitly request it. But this is weighed against improving the most typical scenarios where users expect to search for and find their results on the first page or few pages, and would rarely go beyond the 10 pages before refining their search criteria. The old adage of "the best place to hide a dead body is on page 2 of Google's search results." Row counts and accurate pagination results for very large or complex data sets can be a rather expensive cost for little benefit.